# IdentityServer4 Setup and Use

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver4

I am very new to this... So, please excuse if this is too basic.

I am taking the plunge into .Net Core MVC and JavaScript for the first time and am trying to get my head around Authentication and Authorization in this new world (to me anyways). I ran into IdentityServer about a week ago and am trying to understand where it should sit in my projects, and how it would handle the Hybrid scenario of an SPA being hosted inside an MVC Page.

I could not find any examples or discussions with this scenario. But maybe I missed it, cos i am sure this is a common scenario now days.

Is the idea:

1. Setup Identity Server with ASP .NET Identity (if you wish) as a separate user store/Authentication/Authorization Server application/Project
2. Create new client apps (in my case new MVC APP) and set them up to connect to the "Identity Provider" that has been set up in #1

If this is the case:

What happens if you have, say, an SPA java script application hosted inside one of the pages of the MVC Client?

Will the JS Client be automatically redirected to login as the MVC Client does if it tries to access a secured resource?

Or, do we need to setup the SPA as a separate client too?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just try to help answering this question based on my experience.
Your js apps should have the authorization token in header every request to server, when your request is failed or returned with Unauthorized status then you should handle your js apps to redirect into your local MVC login page.

Because I'm very sure that your login page should handle the logic to redirect into IdentityServer login page for authentication.